# Building ARM code on OS X

Tags: ios, macos, arm, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I am targeting the Cortex-A7 (ARMv7-A)

As a test:

**bootstrap.s**

```
.globl _start
_start:
    mov sp,#0x00010000
    bl main
hang: b hang
```

**main.c**

```
int main(void) { return 0; }
```

Trying:

```
$ as -arch armv7 -march=armv7-a -mcpu=cortex-a7 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 bootstrap.s -o bootstrap.o
$ file bootstrap.o
bootstrap.o: Mach-O object arm
$ clang -c -arch armv7 -march=armv7-a -mcpu=cortex-a7 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 main.c -o main.o
$ file main.o
notmain.o: Mach-O object arm
```

Confirms the compilation of Mach-O arm object files (also verified using `hexdump`, `otool`, `gobjdump`)

But now we try to link them together:

```
$ ld -e _start -arch armv7 bootstrap.o main.o -o foo
ld: warning: -ios_version_min not specified, assuming 6.0
ld: building for iOS, but linking in object file built for OSX, file 'bootstrap.o' for architecture armv7
```

And we have some issues. Not sure what's going on here. I haven't asked to link-in any iOS-related stuff. Using the `-t` linker flag confirms that no other objects are being linked in. Not sure why it thinks `bootstrap.o` is built for OS X when it clearly is a Mach-O arm file. Not sure if I'm passing the right flags to the assembler (pretty much all of them are undocumented?) or the linker

Note that this is for a bare-metal mini-project running on RPi2. I'm going to `gobjcopy` the linked executable object to a flat binary anyways. I'm just working with Mach-O since that's the only object type the system linker on OS X is capable of working with (and fat Mach-O). If I built a separate cross-compiler, I would be doing the exact same thing, instead I'd be linking ELF files before converting them to flat binary (I can output ELF32 files using clang/llvm anyways, I just cant link them). Seems silly to build a separate cross-compiler when clang/llvm is a perfectly suitable cross-compiler that's able to target my microarchitecture

Comment: (I've reposted this from an earlier question, since the question has changed so dramatically)

Comment: I think you should probably use a cross compiler for your architecture (raspberry-pi) instead of using the ios ones, since you wouldn't be able to run on raspberry pi mach-o binaries anyway

Comment: Indeed; raspberry pi will use ELF object file format, and not Mach-O, so you need a different set of cross-compilation tools, and it's probably next to impossible to get working, compared to using Linux.

Comment: @pqnet I'm going to `gobjcopy` the resultant Mach-O to a flat binary

Comment: I bet as has a command line option or pseudo op to set the OS type in the bootstrap.o binary. Does as use clang's integrated assembler or is it a stand alone binary on OS X? Maybe run the clang command line with -v and possibly -no-integrated-as to see what clang is doing. Otherwise you could look at my ELLCC project. Binaries are available to run on the Mac. http://ellcc.org